# A comma seperated list of numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print out from 1 to 1320 like d1,d2,d3,d4 and so on

The command `>>> list(range(1320))` will print out like 1,2, 3 etc. so I tried with `d(list(range(1320)))` but it says `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`

So my question id how to print the numbers like d1,d2,d3 .....

Maybe I am missing very basic syntax here. Any help?

Comment: `["d" + str(i) for i in range(1320)]` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list(range(1320))` builds a list out of that range of numbers, and when that list is shown in your Python session, it lists the elements separated by commas. `[0, 1, 2, ...]`

If you want to build a list of `d0, d1, d2` etc. you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>> ['d%s'%i for i in range(1320)]
['d0', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', ....
```

But if you actually want to just print those strings separated by commas, you can use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>>> print(', '.join(['d%s'%i for i in range(1320)]))
d0, d1, d2, d3, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension like this:

```
['d{}'.format(i) for i in range(1320)]
```

of for Python3.6 and higher:

```
[f'd{i}' for i in range(1320)]
```

Comment: use f-strings, `[f'd{i}' for i in range(1320)]` .
much prettier :)

Comment: @moshevi yep, just added it:)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>>['d'+str(i) for i in range(1320)]
```

---

This is another way to do the same in one line using basic list comprehension.
Just loop till 1230 and concatenate with 'd'.